# Headers in to_latex

Tags: python, pandas, export

lets assume I have a dataframe `potential` with some energies depending on an angle:

```
121.7352                         -3686.7807696787
105                              -3686.6995320774
110                              -3686.7274964541
115                              -3686.6904245431
120                              -3686.7741522700
125                              -3686.7919721470
130                              -3686.8060341619
135                              -3686.8165389535
```

The column headers are `['angle', 'energy']`.

Now I want to export this to a LaTeX table with:

```
potential.to_latex('potential.tex', index = False)
```

How can I get column headers in the exported table like:

```
['Angle in $^\\circ$', 'Energy in kJ / mole']
```

Please note that I know that I can rename the columns of my `potential` dataframe before export and rename them back aterwards. But I do not want to do so if not necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pandas accepts an optional `header` argument containing column aliases:

```
aliases = ['Angle in $^\\circ$', 'Energy in kJ / mole']
potential.to_latex('potential.tex', index=False,
                   header=aliases)
```

The same holds true for the `to_string` method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Tabulate](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tabulate) for that.

e.g.

```
>>> table = [["spam",42],["eggs",451],["bacon",0]]
>>> headers = ["item", "qty"]
>>> print tabulate(table, headers, tablefmt="simple")
item      qty
------  -----
spam       42
eggs      451
bacon       0
```

You can pass `tablefmt="latex"` as an argument to generate Latex tables.

Comment: Thank you very much. I waited for other answers that don't introduce new libraries, but there are none coming and your answer solves my problem. ;)

Comment: Due to the changes in pandas, there is a cleaner solution now.